# My prefix is a young man, My suffix needs a hand

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

- My prefix is a young man.
- My suffix needs a hand.
- My infix is summing it up.
- My purpose is going up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word is

> **LADDERING**

---

My prefix is a young man.

> 'LAD'

My suffix needs a hand.

> 'RING'

My infix is summing it up.

> 'ADD' or even 'ADDER'

My purpose is going up.

> [Laddering](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laddering) refers to ladders, which are used to climb up somewhere/something.

Comment: I think you've got it, but rot13("Ynqqrevat" znxrf zber frafr, jvgu evat nf fhssvk naq nqqre nf vasvk, jvgu gur cerfrag cnegvpvcyr ersreevat gb na npgvivgl engure guna na bowrpg)

Comment: @tmpearce agreed and I've edited but was slighlty hesitant as I'm not really 100% sure on the definition bit. Anyways its definitely one of the two :)

Comment: Naq V whfg gubhtug vg jnf re, nf va "re, tvzzr n unaq?" ;)

Comment: @Walt I was also considering that at one stage :P

Comment: I don't think that's the right word. The verb Ynqqre does not refer to the use of the noun Ynqqre so the last clue doesn't make sense (the word does exist as a verb but its meaning is not about going up).

Comment: @Chris There is no reason why it has to be a verb. The clue simply says it's purpose is to go up, which is undeniably what you use it for. I would be incredibly surprised if this was the wrong word

Comment: But a word ending in ing is a verb. If you take the ing off the end then I would agree it fits the final clue (but not the second as your pre edit suggested) but usually if a clue only refers to part of a word then it will specify that as it did in every part of the clue. So the final clue should refer to the whole word and that isn't a word that means "going up". That having been said I will agree that the balance of probabilities is that you have the right word but that the riddle is a little lacking (IMO).

Comment: @Chris [Merriam-Webster defines it as a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laddering) and it simply refers to many of them, so I think it still works

Comment: I stand corrected then! I can't remember which dictionary I looked at but it only referenced it as a word relating to tights as a verb. My apologies!

Comment: @Chris no worries! I also found that and that was one of the reasons I was hesitant to change it to the longer version :)